Use Smart Folder as default Finder folder
I tried to follow the answer to Use smart folder as Finders default folder, nothing happened for me.
I'm on Mac OS Sonoma Version 14.5 (23F79) with the beta program, but my Terminal seems to just ignore my inquiry and I was wondering if anyone here who knows about Terminal code would help.


The new smart folder I made was called "Recents" but finder doesn't allow me to choose it as a default folder

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is this what you're trying? I made a new smart folder with search: items last opened yesterday on my Mac. Saved that as "Yesterday", and it shows in Finder as "/Users/me/Library/Saved Searches/Yesterday.savedSearch". Opening it directly works. Then I tried to make it the new folder target: defaults write com.apple.finder NewWindowTargetPath '/Users/me/Library/Saved Searches/Yesterday.savedSearch', then killall Finder to refresh. read-ing that default looks correct, but Finder -> New Window still opens '/Users/me/Documents'. Same result with non-smart folder. Seems broken.

Can you find error/complaints from  Finder in Console.app?
